# Apache Airflow for PHP scripts

Tags: php, airflow

I need to execute and control PHP scripts hourly. Of couse I can use crond to execute the scripts, but crond comes without user interface and consecutive scripts are hard to build / control / monitor.

[Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) seems a very good tool for this kind of PHP workflows.

But there is no PHP-Operator available. i just found [Python, Bash and other operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/index.html).

I tried using the Bash operator to execute PHP CLI but did not succeed yet.

How to make PHP executable from within Airflow?

Comment: I am not sure why you would need php to run php scripts on an interval. You could use a line line of bash to invoke a php script: `php script.php`.

Comment: @MaartenDev why? PHP is a great CLI tool with many libraries available. And I have lots of scripts running unattended in batch mode. I'll try your invocation suggestion. Maybe I need to install PHP into the Docker container first

Comment: When the automation platform limits you to the available options you can always use another language like bash to invoke the script using the `php` binary.

Comment: Perfect. I'd like to see if somehone has already done this job. There are different appraches: executing PHP in the airflow container, in a different container, over curl / nginx and so on. What are best practices?